# Are home users vulnerable to the wcrypt malware "outbreak"?

Tags: windows, networking, security, virus, malware

Let me see if I get it all right...

Hackers are exploiting the vulnerability that was leaked from NSA files using wcrypt(all other the news today), which seems to be a worm virus: it searches for new computers to attack.
Since windows XP doesn't have updates anymore it is unprotected and new windows systems are protected if the computer has been updated in March at minimum.
The malware seems to infect through SMB and RDP ports. Since most home users are behind router's firewalls I imagine the problem is bigger after the malware is inside a network. So I would think that the biggest risk for personal computers(as opposed to working stations in a company) is for laptops in a public network.

Did I miss something? Is this all right? I guess because of the lack of firewalls in a lot of public networks, this malware is still a serious threat to home users right? Judging by how often people skip updates and that I have personally seen lots of windows systems that weren't able to update at all because of bugs in windows update and the fact that March wasn't long ago, I guess a lot to personal laptops are at risk...

Thing is: all the news are talking about companies being affected by this vulnerability+wcrypt and not home users. It seems as though they are forgetting to ask home users to really check if their systems are up-to-date just because Microsoft released the patch for it in March and this is really odd.

Comment: Like all malware, you have to introduce it to the system, very few malware spreads automatically, wcrypt isn't a exception

Comment: Even those few exceptions spread only after being introduced to a network.

Comment: @Ramhound WCrypt is a worm that spreads across the Internet. If you haven’t firewalled off your SMB ports and have an unpatched system, you can get it.

Comment: @Spiff You make it sound like the vulnerability can't be patched or more importantly hasn't been patched.

Comment: *which is Irresponsibility* I can't find an article that specifically says this worm is spreading by itself, I see that it's being spread by email, and logic dictates that once in a network it might spread itself, but blindly scanning and spreading across the entire internet (to be frank) seems out of the talent behind this malware.

Comment: "While WanaCrypt0r has been observed spreading across local networks by utilizing the above exploit, its initial infection into a network is still being discovered completely." So the intial infection path hasn't been determined. [Malwarebytes](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/cybercrime/2017/05/wanacrypt0r-ransomware-hits-it-big-just-before-the-weekend/)

Comment: [never mind](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/threat-analysis/2017/05/the-worm-that-spreads-wanacrypt0r/)

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for sharing this last article

Comment: Worth pointing out the worm is being manually spread through spam or targeted at specific targets but will also attempt to spread across the wider internet (although it appears that's partly broken in the current version) but it's also very important people install the darn patch which was released over a month ago.  Be a good citizen of the internet and patch your machines!!

Comment: I don't use windows of course :P but I've passed the word to family members that don't know anything about computers other than to switch it on and off and opening facebook.

Comment: [All applicable Windows Versions](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4012598)

Comment: @Ramhound Is Windows 7 not vulnerable? It doesn't appear on those search results.

Comment: @DavidPostill Windows 7 and Windows 10 must have been patched by another KB, I found KB4012598, from a random article.

Comment: [Windows 7](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4012215), [Everything Else](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS17-010) cause the catalog website errors out on iOS

Comment: @Ramhound I found it. It is in [MS17-010 Security Update for Microsoft Windows SMB Server (4013389)](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS17-010)